# Why ++(*p) changes the pointer value?

Tags: c++, c, pointers

If I have this code:

```
int A[5] = { 2, 1, 3, 55 };
int *p = A;
cout << ++(*p);
```

the result is `3` and the value of the first position of `A` is `3` also, why?

I mean, by hierarchy of operators `()` is more hierarchical than `++`, then we would need operate `*p` first:

```
++(*p) => ++(2) => 3
```

with any change in `A` vector?

Comment: `*p` returns a reference to the pointed to object, `++` modifies that in place. What is unclear about this?

Comment: it does not change the value of the pointer, why do you think so ? print the pointer before and after, you will see that it is the same

Comment: Instead of `++(*p) => ++(2) => 3`, use `++(*p) => ++(A[0]) => 3`. An array element `A[0]` is incremented, not an integer value `2`.

Comment: The whole point of `++` is to change the operand. Why do you expect it to not do that?

Comment: OP is perhaps asking whether the parentheses make a difference. He seems to think that the parentheses discard the lvalue-ness of the expression. After all, when we are learning, we formulate hypotheses and try to verify them and discard wrong hypotheses.

Comment: It doesn't change the pointer value; it changes the value of *the pointed-at thing*. And the reason it does so is because the code translates as "find the pointed-at thing, and change it".

Comment: If `*p` were not an *lvalue* it would be hard to modify the array, that's why `p[0]++` also modifies the array. C++ is slightly more explicit about this -- the `[]` operator returns a *reference* (e.g. `SomeType & operator [] ( arg )`) in order to allow the value to be changed.

Comment: Sorry to my bad english, I mean, by hierarchy of operators: https://slideplayer.com/slide/12428531/74/images/20/Hierarchy+of+operators.jpg

The pointer reference and the '++' have the same level, and In the case of ++*p I would need to operate from the right to the left, then I would operate first "*p" and then the "++", thus: ++*p => ++(2) => error, why it seems ++*p is broken the rule of hierarchy of operators?

Comment: `++` is the increment-and-use-result operator. What do you think it should be incrementing if not the value at `*p`?

Answer (score 19):

`*p` is not just "2", it's an *lvalue*, i.e. this "2" has a well-defined location.
The value at this location is modified by the `++` operator - by definition of the `++` operator.

If you don't want to modify the value, use `+ 1` instead: `*p + 1`.

---

In C/C++, *lvalue* is a value with a defined location in memory. This value can be changed - by an assignment, incremented, decrement.
For example,

```
int x = 0;
x = 1; // ok, x is an lvalue, assignment changes the value from 0 to 1

int *p = &x;
*p = 2; // ok, *p is an lvalue, assignment changes the value from 1 to 2
```

In contrast, an *rvalue* is a value without a defined location - for example, a result of an arithmetic operation. This value can't be assigned, incremented or decremented (it doesn't mean it can't be used in a larger expression).

For example,

```
int x = 0, y = 1;
(x + y) = 3; // compilation error, (x + y) is an rvalue

2++; // compilation error, 2 is an rvalue
```

---

Here's a pretty simple article explaining lvalues / rvalues: https://eli.thegreenplace.net/2011/12/15/understanding-lvalues-and-rvalues-in-c-and-c

Comment: For a novice c++ user "lvalue" might be a bit hard to read. If you also explain that it is meant to be a "reference to" will help for beginners I believe!

Answer (score 5):

The `++(*p)` is the same as `++p[0]` and `++A[0]` All change the first element of the array.

> Why ++(*p) changes the pointer value

It does not. The pointer value is value kept in the `p`. It is called  "address" or "reference". It does not change.

Answer (score 0):

It's worth noting the overuse of '*' in C++ which usually confuses novices.

Here:

```
int *p = A;
```

'*' means you are declaring p as a variable that can store a memory address (a pointer), and assigning the address of the first position of A (it's the same as &(A[0]) ).

Here:

```
++(*p)
```

' *' means you are looking into 'p' content (derreferencing the address of 'p' which is the same as the address of 'A[0]'). Then the '++' increments the value which reflects both.

Just to confirm, after this assignment (int *p = A;) print the values of 'p', 'A' and '&A[0]'.